# Weird callback execution order in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

Consider the following code:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

d1 = Deferred()
d2 = Deferred()

def f1(result):
    print 'f1',

def f2(result):
    print 'f2',

def f3(result):
    print 'f3',

def fd(result):
    return d2

d1.addCallback(f1)
d1.addCallback(fd)
d1.addCallback(f3)

#/BLOCK====
d2.addCallback(f2)
d1.callback(None)
#=======BLOCK/

d2.callback(None)
```

This outputs what I would expect:

```
f1 f2 f3
```

However when I swap the order of the statements in BLOCK to

```
#/BLOCK====
d1.callback(None)
d2.addCallback(f2)
#=======BLOCK/
```

i.e. Fire d1 before adding the callback to d2, I get:

```
f1 f3 f2
```

I don't see why the time of firing of the deferreds should influence the callback execution order.
Is this an issue with Twisted or does this make sense in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr —** When you return a deferred (`d2`) from a callback (`fd`), it's inserted into the callback chain of whatever deferred (`d1`) called `fd`. This is done by adding a continuation of `d1`'s callback chain as a callback on `d2`, so if you add a callback to `d2` *after* firing `d1`, it gets tacked on *after* `d1`'s continuation.

---

I think you're missing the fact that deferreds aren't asynchronous in-and-of themselves, they're just a more structured way to chain callbacks and error handlers in asynchronous code. The callbacks aren't called at some unspecified later time, they're called *when the deferred is fired*. If you want this to be later, you'll need to integrate your calls with a `reactor`.

So maybe that makes the answer to this a little more obvious:

> I don't see why the time of firing of the deferreds should influence the callback execution order.

It will if you change the callbacks *after* you fire the deferred.

## Explanation of your code

### In the first example:

1. `d1.callback(None)` causes `d1` to be fired
2. `f1` is called (prints "f1")
3. `fd` is called (returns `d2`)

Now things stop, because `d2` has been [inserted in the callback chain](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto13) for `d1` between `f1` and `f3`, but has not yet been fired. Then...

1. `d2.callback(None)` causes `d2` to be fired
2. `f2` is called (prints "f2")
3. `d1`'s callback chain resumes; so `f3` is called (prints "f3")

### In the second example

1. `d1.callback(None)` causes `d1` to be fired
2. `f1` is called (prints "f1")
3. `fd` is called (returns `d2`)

Here `d2` is again inserted into the callback chain. The way this is done is by [adding a continuation of the current callback chain](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.1.0/twisted/internet/defer.py#L557) as a callback to `d2`. So even though you explicitly add `f2` as a callback on `d2`, it's added **after** the continuation of `d1`'s callback chain. Hence...

1. `d2.callback(None)` causes `d2` to be fired; this causes `d1`'s callback chain to be continued, starting with...
2. `f3` is called (prints "f3")
3. `d2`'s next callback in **it's** chain is `f2`, so...
4. `f2` is called (prints "f2")

Comment: This makes sense AFTER d2 fires and f3 has been called. Then there is no way to call f2 before f3 without wormhole technology. However, d2 hasn't fired yet in my example. so f3 hasn't been called yet either. You can still get the order right!

Comment: @SlashV - sorry, I removed my detailed explanations because they were incorrect (and therefore really confusing)! I'll have to think a little more about what happens with deferreds being called synchronously.

Comment: @SlashV - okay, figured it out! Let me know if the language is confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand now why it works the way it does. I am still not sure why it is necessary though. I'll have to look into the continuation thing.

Comment: @SlashV - I'm not a Twisted dev, but it seems like a sane way of having pauseable/resumable callback chains that automatically incorporate returned deferreds. Keep in mind that your code (synchronous, interleaved callback-adding and firing) is not really an expected use case, and consistency here would be ambiguous anyway. So it's probably not a design priority to "get it right".

Comment: My idea was like this: d1 one fires and calls f1, then fd. This is a deferred, so we're done, but store the point where we left off. Then when d2 fires, it can call its callbacks (present at the time it fires! so f2 get called) and then call the callbacks from d1 from where it left off with the correct result for fd (the result of f2)... but maybe I'm having a brainfart here. When I have some time I'll try and see if that could work.

Comment: @SlashV - I can certainly see how you'd think it'd work like that, but it comes down to how deferreds that are returned from callbacks are treated. Effectively you need the returned deferred (`d2`) to "take on" the rest of `d1`'s callback chain, so even if it hasn't been fired it still knows where to pick up from. Hence, a callback added to `d2` at this point ends up getting called after `d1`'s original chain (now `d2`'s chain) is completed. The real point, though, is that in normal Twisted code the callback chain is constructed before **any** deferreds are fired.

Comment: The use of the reactor in this example is weird and misleading.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone - it's not what I'd usually do (since I'd usually structure things more than this), but it's exactly what's in [the documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html). Unless you mean the `callWhenRunning` calls?

Comment: @detly - yes, the callWhenRunning calls.  They're just an obscure way to fire the two Deferreds in the order you want.  You can change the example to not use a reactor at all and still fire the Deferreds in the desired order.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone - the OP can already do that, their first example goes through the callbacks in the desired order without using a reactor. Since what I was trying to demonstrate is probably tangential to the real question, I suppose I might as well remove the example.